# Speed up execution of this function

Tags: performance-tuning, parallelization

I would like to speed up **this following function**:

```
assignvalue[xval_, zval_] := 
Module[{xtest = 
  Flatten[Position[IntervalMemberQ[#, N[xval]] & /@ intdomain, 
    True]]},
Reverse[
 SortBy[Select[
   Partition[
    Riffle[Map[inter[[#]][x] &, xtest] /. x -> N[xval], 
     values[[#]] & /@ xtest], 2], #[[1]] < N[zval] &], First]]][[
 1, 2]];
```

Function should assign value (value from the list `values`) to the point (point defined by some `xval` and `zval`), based on the position of point with respect to the closest curve in the z direction, lying below the point.

Additional inforamtion, random test `data` and `values` :
There is `100 + 2` curves, which were created by `data` interpolation. Data and values are shown below

```
m = 100;
n = 100;
offset = {-5, 5};
numbofxvalues = 10;
xvalues = Table[RandomReal[{0, n}, numbofxvalues], {i, 1, m}];
f[x_, z_] := {x, z};
maxzvalues = 1000;
di = maxzvalues/m
veryfirstline = {{1, 1 + offset[[1]]}, {n, 1 + offset[[1]]}};
verylastline = {{1, maxzvalues + offset[[2]]}, {n, 
maxzvalues + offset[[2]]}};

data = SortBy[#, First] & /@ 
Module[{k = 1}, 
Table[(# + {0, RandomReal[offset]}) & /@ (f[#, i] & /@ 
    xvalues[[k++]]), {i, 1, maxzvalues, di}]];
data = Join[{veryfirstline}, {verylastline}, data];
values = Range[Length@data];
```

Interpolation is shown here

```
inter = Table[Unique[inter$], {i, 1, Length@data}];
Table[inter[[i]] = 
Interpolation[data[[i]], InterpolationOrder -> 1], {i, 1, 
Length@data}];
intdomain = 
Interval[#] & /@ 
Flatten[Table[(inter[[i]])["Domain"], {i, 1, Length@data}], 1];
```

I am applying function `assignvalue` to list of pairs (called `grid`). List `grid` represents points in 2D space.

```
gridstepx = n/800;
gridstepz = maxzvalues/800;
grid = Table[{N[i], N[j]}, {i, 1, n, gridstepx}, {j, 1, maxzvalues, 
gridstepz}];
```

Application of function `assignvalue` to values in `grid` is shown below

```
solutions = Apply[assignvalue, #, {1}] & /@ grid; // AbsoluteTiming
(*Output:*)
{1194.12, Null}
```

Computation of `solutions` took on my machine **1194.12** seconds. If somebody could think of some speeding up the evaluation of this function, I will be very grateful. The parallel implementation will be also accepted as an answer since I can use 2 subkernels for parallel computation.

**Example**
For some given coordinates of point (`xpoint` and `zpoint`) the function will at first go throug all the interpolation intervals (`intdomain`) and will pick only those curves for which `xpoint`(highlighted by dashed *Blue* line) lies in interpolation interval of some particular curve (curves satisfying this criterion are plotted in *Green* colour). After that the function will idetify the "serial "number/"name" of curve (curves are denoted by number from `values` list) which lies below the point a it is closest to this point (solution curve plotted in *Red* colour).

```
xpoint = 5;(*x coordinate of example point*)
zpoint = 507;(*z coordinate of example point*)
curveswithsamexpoint = 
Flatten[Position[IntervalMemberQ[#, N[xpoint]] & /@ intdomain, 
True]];(*curves satisfying criterion*)

Show[Table[
Plot[Tooltip[inter[[i]][x], values[[i]]], {x, intdomain[[i, 1, 1]], 
intdomain[[i, 1, 2]]}, 
PlotRange -> {{1, n}, {1 - 5, maxzvalues + 5}}, 
PlotStyle -> 
Which[i == assignvalue[xpoint, zpoint], Red, 
MemberQ[curveswithsamexpoint, i], 
Green, ! MemberQ[curveswithsamexpoint, i], Black], 
Epilog -> {PointSize[Large], Red, Point[{xpoint, zpoint}], Blue, 
Dashed, Line[{{xpoint, 1 + offset[[1]]}, {xpoint, 
maxzvalues + offset[[2]]}}]}], {i, 1, Length@data}]]
```

[image]

Comment: Could you explain in a bit more detail what you want to achieve? (preferably with a more minimal example) As it stands, it is very difficult to understand what your current version is doing exactly

Comment: @LukasLang, I added an example

Comment: Are you at all able to minimize this? There is a direct correlation between how minimal the problem is (in its current form, it really isn't minimized) and how much help you're likely to get on the question.